# Will performSelectorOnMainThread interrupt current code block?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

If I have a background thread doing some network stuff, and some of the background methods make 'performSelectorOnMainThread' calls, will/can these calls interrupt execution of the current code block (which is being executed on the main thread)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will and can not. The `performSelector` group of methods schedule actions on the run loop. Only after your current code block returns to the run loop, these actions will be performed. (Assuming with "the current code block" you mean your code running on the main thread)

Answer (score 1):

If `waitUntilDone` is set to `YES`, then absolutely it will definitely interrupt execution of the code calling `performSelectorOnMainThread`. If it's set to `NO` then it will queue the selector to be performed on the main thread.

If the caller of `performSelectorOnMainThread` is not the main thread, then whether or not the selector gets run before your "current code block" finishes will depend entirely upon the state the CPU is in. There might be more than one CPU so you might have 2 of your threads scheduled at the same time, or just the OS might have decided to schedule the main thread instead of your current thread after some time.

So basically, yes, these calls can interrupt execution of the current code block, just in the same way as you should be familiar with from multi-threaded programming.

[By "current code block" I am assuming you mean the caller of `performSelectorOnMainThread`]

**Update:**

Ah, right, you mean "Can it interrupt the code which is currently being executed on the main thread?". The answer to that, is definitely not. It is scheduled on the main thread's run loop to run next time round the loop.

Comment: This is wrong. These calls can *not* interrupt execution of the current code block executing on the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to reflect that current code block is running on main thread.

Comment: Right, it's been clarified in the question now. Updated answer.

Comment: Then, still, the "current code block" on the main thread is executed until it returns to the run loop. *Then* the posted selector is run. If `waitUntilDone` is set to `YES`, the calling thread stalls until this has finished. If the main thread is currently in some loop, taking 10 seconds, the calling thread will have to wait until these 10 seconds are over, plus the time taken by the selector which was posted.

Comment: Yep exactly. I misunderstood what he meant by "the current code block" at first. I updated with reasoning and the answer based on confusion being cleared up.